# How to symlink with cifs ext3 disk? Permission denied

Tags: symlink, cifs

`$ sudo ln -s ~/somefile /media/fritz` fails with `Permission denied`.

I'm perfectly able to `$ touch /media/fritz/foo.txt`

/etc/fstab/:
`//fritz.box/FRITZ.NAS/ /media/fritz cifs credentials=/home/me/.credentials,vers=1.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount`

I tried `ext2` and `ext3` as format for the usb stick attached without any success. `ext4` is no option since not recognized by the nas-router (fritzbox)

Comment: does your CIFS setup support symlinks? That's not a windows feature, so I'm not sure it can be done over CIFS. (I honestly don't know!)

Comment: What happens with `sudo ln -s ~/somefile <ip for //fritz.box/>/FRITZ.NAS/`?  If you get `Permission Denied` even with the long form, I believe @MarcusMüller may be correct

Comment: You are trying to create a link on the FritzNAS that is pointing somewhere on your local machine - from the NAS side of view, this does not seem sensible I believe. I assume you meant to create a link on your local machine, pointing to the Fritz?